# Does the Nighthawk M1 support IPv6?

Tags: router, modem

I've searched for hours for a good answer on whether the Nighthawk M1 (MR1100-100EUS) supports IPv6 but found no definite answer. Some say it does support it while some say it doesn't. Most people are just talking about the US networks in those threads...

Does it support IPv6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, it does support native IPv6 everywhere (LTE, Wi-Fi, Ethernet) despite Netgear staff stating that it doesn't in [multiple old posts](https://community.netgear.com/t5/Mobile-Routers-Hotspots-Modems/Nighthawk-M1-IPV6-setup/td-p/1412640).

I bought one myself to try and it does support it in a good way.

The only thing I did was setting the APN to IPv4 + IPv6, it was IPv4 only originally as it was probably using some old profile (my operator got native IPv6 last year).

Here's a screenshot from test-ipv6.com:

[image: IPv6 test results for Nighthawk M1]

However, there are not many IPv6 options at all, there's no way to set any custom IPv6 DNS Server for example. But it works fine, my devices have unique IPv6 addresses 100% of the time.